# How to group by twice or restrict a group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a location. A location has invoices. Invoices have fees. I want to get all the fees for a given month for a given location.

Here's what I can do:

```
SELECT 
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(invoices.invoiceDate) , MONTH(invoices.invoiceDate), '01'), '%Y-%m-%d') as invoiceMonth, 
    AVG(fees.amount) as averageMonthlyInvoice, 
    SUM(fees.amount) as totalMonthlyInvoice 
    from invoices as invoices 
    inner join fees as fees 
        on fees.invoiceId = invoices.id
    where invoices.locationId = 1
    group by invoiceMonth
```

This second one would give me the average and total invoice information for an location. I want to be able to do this for all locations at once.
Here's what I want to do:

```
SELECT 
    invoices.locationId as locationId,
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(invoices.invoiceDate) , MONTH(invoices.invoiceDate), '01'), '%Y-%m-%d') as invoiceMonth, 
    AVG(fees.amount) as averageMonthlyInvoice, 
    SUM(fees.amount) as totalMonthlyInvoice 
    from invoices as invoices 
    inner join fees as fees 
        on fees.invoiceId = invoices.id
    group by invoiceMonth, locationId
```

However, this last one would just average and total all invoices, not giving me the information for each specific location.

Comment: Can you perhaps supply same data and expected results?  Your last query looks correct to me though since you are grouping by the locationid...

Comment: You are selecting columns which do not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause and are not aggregates.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen -- Since you can group by a column alias, which columns were left out? Not completely understanding your comment. Both queries look right to me...

Comment: The second one gives the information for all locations.  That is what the `group by` does.

Comment: Your second query gives you one record for a single location Id and the aggregates (sum and average) of the records for that location Id with the same month and year. Did you want something else?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using `ORDER BY (conditions)` might also help you get the data return you desire?